# I need to add a tick mark on selected option of dropdown. I am using angular material. Not getting the solution

Tags: angular, angular-material

Example:
options,
A
B
C
D

If i select B from the dropdown, I need to add a tick symbol next to the selected option.

Comment: Welcome to SOF, please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] when posting a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an css class to create checkmark after selected option something like

```
.checkmark:before {
  content:'L';
  font-family: arial;
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  color: green;
  height:1em;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

then set this class on selected option using ngclass

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of data" [ngClass]="{'checkmark':item==selectedValue}" [value]="item">
        {{item}}
      </mat-option>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-kzzdmu)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should use the multiple attribute in your HTML:

```
 <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

The complete example please refer: 
https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview -Multiple selection 
or go directly in: 
https://stackblitz.com/angular/kopmxoryagml?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts